# How to change a WPF control's visibility from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I've an WPF application where tried to implement MVVM pattern and Prism 2. I have a Usercontrol which has subscribed to an event fired from another Usercontrol. I would like to toggle visibility of few child elements in the subscribing control. Events are fired properly, even I am successfully able to bind data to some elements. How do I bind Visibility or any style property for that matter with the ViewModel and change them dynamically.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can have a boolean property in your ViewModel and bind that property to the Visibility property of your controls. Since you will be asigning a boolean value and the Visibility property is expecting a Visibility enumeration value, you will have to use the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) converter to make the conversion,

```
<Style.Resources>
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Style.Resources>

<Image Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowImage, 
                    Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Ezequiel Jadib

Comment: Somehow this didn't work for me. I declared converter in Usercontrol.Resources section and used bindings as you have explained in the comment.

Answer (score 10):

Although adding a Boolean property and using a value converter works, I would recommend adding a property of type Visibility to your ViewModel, e.g.

```
public Visibility ImageVisibility
{
    get { return shouldShowImage ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed }
}
```

The advantage of this method is you don't need to write a converter for every property you want to express in a visual way (e.g. for a stock level that turns a label red when it drops below 10, you could have a converter you use once or just expose a StockLabelBrush property from your VM)

Comment: While this answer is elegant, there's a problem with it.  If the program changes `shouldShowImage`, that change is not sent to the view.

Comment: That is true, but there are a couple of ways to handle the problem. You can either handle the `PropertyChanged` event from `shouldShowImage` and raise a new `PropertyChanged` event, or only allow access to `shouldShowImage` through a wrapper property that raises events for both properties.

Comment: I can see two things going on here, (i) I decide whether something is true or false (which seems appropriate for a VM to do) and (ii) I take that boolean value and decide whether some control should be visible or not (which seems appropriate for the View. I'd have thought using a converter here would be ideal in terms of keeping the V/VM boundary clean.

Comment: @PeteH, the difference between a ViewModel and a Model is that the ViewModel is concerned with what is displayed in the view. Without that logic in the ViewModel you just have a Model. Also, it is very easy to test the element on the view becomes visible when the Boolean changes if the logic is in the VM.

Comment: that's bad because if you port your code to different .Net technology e.g. MAUI this wouldn't work, whereas boolean approach is more portable

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple solution for people who run into this issue.

In your view model, create a "Visibility" property like so:

```
public Visibility ShowModifyButtons
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowModifyButtonsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowModifyButtonsProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowModifyButtonsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowModifyButtons", typeof(Visibility), typeof(FileMatchViewModel),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
```

In your XAML, bind to it like so:

```
 <Button Focusable="False" Content="Save" Width="100" Margin="10" Visibility="{Binding ShowModifyButtons}"/>
```

Now, from your view model, you can set `ShowModifyButtons` to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Visible` as needed.